# Difference between H2 control and input shaping

Tags: discrete-signals, control-systems, numerical-algorithms, resonance

Let us assume a system with external disturbance to reject. The system that is used for controlling has vibrations, that we would like to avoid.
We assume moreover that the dynamics are known (10% error in frequencies and damping factor), either in a state-space model or transfer functions.

H2 control seems a classical way though tedious numerically to reject both the perturbations and the resonance : a LQG for the observer part and the LQR for avoiding amplifications with resonance. This implies solving two Riccati equations.
At the same time, there is a field called input shaping (see for example the paper Tutorial on Input Shaping/Time Delay Control of Maneuvering Flexible Structures). By having some kind of trajectory planning on the inputs, it would be possible to reduce transient responses and make sure that the overshoot remains small. Therefore, the LQR part would simplify a lot : it would no longer be necessary to consider a dynamical system for the actuators, but just a static. And the input shaping would do the rest.

What would be the differences in terms of performance between :

- full H2 control
- LQG + assumption of static actuator solving the LQG problem + input shaping
  ?